# I got a "numpy.ndarray object is not callable" as error when trying to run a code in jupyter

Tags: matrix, dashboard, interactive

```
# build model for confusion_matrix
threshold = 0.5
y_pred_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, -1]
y_pred = y_pred_proba > threshold
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

i tried the above code and was expecting a 2*2 matrix array which i can then use in conjunction to a widget. However running the code half way to check it's effectiveness resulted in an
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable